# Is there any way to use "f-string" for a multiline string, which is stored in a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to send email with html template.The template is in a html file and there are some variable in this. If I read the file and store its text in a variable :

```py
with open('test.html', 'r') as f:
    html = f.read()
```

Is it possible to use f-string in 'html' variable?

Answer (score 1):

The f-strings (also called [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)), are a part of the language syntax and are a way to describe strings **in code**. What you want to achieve here is something different.

What you describe is commonly known as templates. The Python standard library provides [Template strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings), but they work a little different then f-strings.

Furthermore, a number of third-party template libraries are mentioned in comments, and you could [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+html+template) on internet for other template libraries (modules/packages) that best suits your application.